# How to take int value in text field from other textfield

Tags: java, swing

I'm new to java. I create project where I have one textField and one button. I make function for button, where I start my other function and it's ok. But I need to take number value from textField as parameter for my function...

```
b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                 int price;
                 int quantity = Integer.parseInt(tf2.getText());
                 int totalamount = price*quantity;
              //need to insert this total amout into textfield tf4 //


             tf4.getText(totalamount); //showing error ;   

            }

        });
```

help me in please ,thank you in advance

Comment: Do you want to set that Total amount in tf4? just do tf4.setText(Integer.toString(totalamount));

Comment: tf4.getText(Integer.toString(totalamount));

Comment: @StanislavL What do you want to say sir by passing parameter from a getter method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple...
You can get integer value from textfield like

> int totalamount = Integer.parseInt(tf2.getText());

getText() method are use to get value from textfield and If this value is integer the you can parse it like Integer.parseInt, If this value is string then you can get this value using toString() method.

and you can set this value like

```
   tf4.setText(String.valueOf(totalamount));
```

setText() method are use to  set text to Textfield.

You can use this value in function call as a parameter to call function like

```
myFunction(totalAmount);// function declaration
```

And use this value in Function Definition like

```
 public void myFunction(int totalamount)// Function Defination
```

You have to read Basic Java. [Here is link which help you](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){ 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
       int price; 
       int quantity = Integer.parseInt(tf2.getText()); 
       //int totalamount = price*quantity; 
       //need to insert this total amout into textfield tf4 //

       tf4.setText(totalamount); //showing error ;   

    }

 });
```

Comment: The error occur because you are actually getting the text from tf4. Instead, you have to set the text to totalamount.

Answer (score 0):

just replace your this line

```
tf4.getText(totalamount);
```

by this one

```
tf4.setText(Integer.toString(totalamount));
```

OR
`tf4.setText(totalamount);`

because `TextField` have overloded methods for setting text for `Strings` and `int`.

Please keep in mind that You never pass a value(by convention of Java) from a getter method.Only parameters can be passed from setter methods (if we are considering them in Beans sense or any other as well).Please follow some basics of Java [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-138747.html) and [here](http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~parrt/doc/java/JavaBasics-notes.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

```
b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{ 
    //put the try catch here so if user didnt put an integer we can do something else
    try
    {
        int price;
        int quantity = Integer.parseInt(tf2.getText());
        int totalamount = price*quantity;

        //need to insert this total amout into textfield tf4 //

        tf4.setText(totalamount);
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException ex)
    {
          //do something like telling the user the input is not a number
    }   

}});
```